# Porque obtengo Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cross-spawn (over 30000ms) al usar npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

Estoy recibiendo el mensaje Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cross-spawn (over 30000ms) cada vez que intento instalar algo con NPM.
estoy ejecutando `sudo npm install -g create-react-app` y me dice eso. Porque será? Ya he intentado borrar la cache de npm, actualizar la version de npm, bajar a una version anterior, desinstalar y volver a instalar, buscar el archivo .npmrc para cambiar el valor del timeout... (por cierto no pude localizar el archivo npmrc pero leí en muchos sitios que esto si funciona, cambiando el timeout a 6000, pero no sé porque no he podido editar ese archivo, no lo encuentro en mi sistema operativo...) y nada de ésto me ha servido. Quisiera saber que opinan y si me pueden ayudar. Tengo varios días googleando jeje

Comment: Usas windows? Puede ser el firewall.

Comment: _no, uso ubuntu mate_

Comment: Revisa si te sirve [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61378723/4326551)

Comment: puede deberse a problemas de conexion.

Comment: ya habia revisado esa página y seguí sus indicaciones pero no logré localizar ese archivo npmrc...

Comment: @Yohanna prueba a conectarte por medio de ethernet.

Comment: _siempre lo he estado jeje, de verdad no se que más intentar..._